# Observable that manages a "request running" variable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In Angular, I'm currently writing a lot of Code repeatedly like this:

- I have service classes that return an `Observable<XYZ>`, that are sending requests to my backend
- In my components I want to make sure that a request is only running once at the same time. So if a request takes a bit longer and the user hits a button again and again it doesn't start a new request. So my component has some `requestRunning` variable and invoking the service then looks like this:

```
myFunction() {
  if (this.requestRunning) {
    return;
  }
  this.requestRunning = true;
  this.myService.callBackend().subscribe(
    success => {
      doSomething();
    },
    error => {
      this.requestRunning = false;
    },
    _ => { // complete
      this.requestRunning = false;
    }
  );
}
```

What I would prefer is something like an Observable which I can pass in the `requestRunning` variable, and that sets it to `true` if the Observable is subscribed to, and set to `false` if the Observable finishes (complete/error).

Does somebody know a cool and DRY solution for this?

Comment: Simply move the ‘request running’ logic to the service maybe..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use exhaustMap operator, this way you won't even need to maintain a variable to keep track of state, here the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/exhaustmap-demo-clles9?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

though you'll need to change the way you are adding the listener on your button:

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    const btn = this.button.nativeElement;

    // this will produce outer observable
    fromEvent(btn, "click")
      .pipe(
        exhaustMap(() => {
          console.log("calling api...");
          // this will produce inner observable, so exhaustMap will wait for inner 
          // observable to complete, until then it any emissions from outer observables are going to be ignored.
          return this.appService.callApi();
        })
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: (apiResponse) => {
          console.log("api response recieved");
        }
      });
  }
```